# Close db connection after each query or end of script

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

It's php application using mysqli.

Someone else suggested to have db connection closed right after each query.

Current system have singleton database connection, so over-created new connection is not issue here. Only unused open connections.(Say, the script has not finished execution and the database is not closed by itself.)

So it seemed that there is something to balance - between the cost of waiting for the script to finish and multiple unnecessary closings of the db connection per script. I tend to think that the first is safer. But I am not very sure if it's sufficient. For example if  I do:

```
$userA->sendMessageTo($userB);
And inside this:
$userA->send($userB);
$userA->useSomePoints();
$userA->flushPointsBalance();
....
```

Imagining each method will have some database operation but this is just one script call/request, if the db open/close happens around each query, this will certainly happen more than once, comparing to not closing it right after each query in method scope.

So which way is better?

Comment: what i've been doing is to leave the db connection open but close each mysqli statement after processing, like they show in the example http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php , then close the db connection at any "exit points" eg on error exit

Answer (score 0):

generally, having your DB wrapper class (or ORM) create a single connection for the entire request and only close it during clean up (either via destructor, or via PHP's cleanup) is okay. if this is a problem, it probably means that something long is happening between your opening and closing of connections, and this is what you should be addressing instead.

causes could be:

1. slow queries that don't make use of indices
2. some other high latency blocking IO (file reading, decoding, etc)

you'll get better gains in terms of effort addressing those issues, rather than looking at how you open and close connections.